# VS: Program can't start because missing libfftw3-3.dll

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, fftw

I'm building my code in Visual Studio 2013 with FFTW 3.3.5 and OpenCV library.

Occasionally I could start my program and perform FFT functions, but sometimes I couldn't because of missing libfftw3-3.dll warning. It just happened so randomly and I didn't change any library dependencies in the settings before the problem appeared.

I also have tried to clean or rebuild solution but it didn't work. Much appreciated for any help.

Answer (score 0):

[Solved] by closing VS then open the solution, clean and rebuild it. It's a weird thing.